# Action Required: Your app is not compliant with Google Play Policies, What is the solution?

Tags: android, google-play-console

Issue details

We found an issue in the following area(s):

```
SPLIT_BUNDLE 31: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Personal Info Data Type - Email Address
SPLIT_BUNDLE 31: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Personal Info Data Type - Phone number
```

[image: Here is the screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

Your app might have any feature that uses user data without their consent. I suggest you visit the "Data safety" section and submit the app's privacy and security practices.

To access the "Data safety" section:

1. Open "Play Console"
2. Scroll to "Policy and programs" and click "App content"
3. Start the "Data safety"
4. Answer all the questions as per your requirement
5. Re-submit the changes for review

Comment: i did that already and selected all options that available but get rejected every time